# Reading website content via MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab

I need to read the content of a website via MATLAB but the problem is when I load the website as:

```
URL = java.net.URL(UrlNew);
urlConnection = URL.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
str = regexprep(fileread(filename),'\s*',' ');
```

The website redirects me to a page which I have first to press "I agree" button and then it goes to the requested page.

How can I handle this situation in MATLAB. I need to somehow click the "Agree" button in MATLAB to have access to the original webpage.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find out the value of the `action` attribute of the form on your original page. You can do this by examining the source code of the page, looking for the form tag containing the Agree button, or by manually clicking on the button and looking at the Network activity tab in the Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug in Firefox.

Once you find this, find out how to send POST requests in Java and simulate the clicking of the button by sending a POST request to the action URL of the form. If you collect the output from the socket after that, it should correspond to the page you want.